# How to get Scrollview total width

Tags: android

How to get **Total width of scrollview** .if i am getting scrollview.getWidth() in ViewTreeobserver then return device width size how to get total width of scrollview.

How to get Total width if Scrollview inner view is device width outside then how to exact width.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView always has only 1 child

so you need to do

```
((ViewGroup)scrollView.getChildAt(0)).getWidth()
```

Comment: Getting size same width with device width in viewtreeobserver.In scrollview outside some data but showing same as device width

Comment: where are you requesting the width?